# No file or directory names are shown in Finder at home directory

Tags: macos, finder

Finder does not show file and directory names in my home directory in list and cover flow view modes. Other columns are okay but name column does not not have a title and it is empty.

I am using Mac OS X 10.9.5.

How can I make it show file/directory names properly in all view modes?

Comment: Sorry, I am confused, your home directory (the one with home icon) should only show folders (names) it will not show files.

Comment: If you are sure that you're viewing your Home directory when this happens, try closing all Finder windows, open Terminal and issue `cd ~`, press the Enter key, then `rm .DS_Store`, Enter key again. Open a new Finder window and select your Home directory; does it properly display now?

Comment: Buscar, it does not show names of folders and files. But when I click on one of them, finder goes into that directory.

Comment: After I did what dougro said in the comment above, problem was not solved. After that, I changed my default directory from home to somewhere else, then I manually went to home directory, problem was still not solved. 

Finally I clicked on the title of the name column and suddenly names are shown again... This is a strange behaviour, but problem seems gone now.